# Silverlight 4 RichtTextBox - how do I get the text without the formatting?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

How do I get the text out of a Silverlight 4 RichTextBox without the formatting?  I know the Xaml property will give me the XAML but I just want the text.

Comment: I have a solution for this - I'll blog it and post a link here as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late, but I will post anyway. There is a trick that involves selecting all the text in code and then accessing the Text propety of the TextSelection object. Like so:

```
myRichTextBox.SelectAll();
var plainText = myRichTextBox.Selection.Text;
```

I am using it in my apps and although it is not the prettiest solution, it works. Found it here:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/184560/422007.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you just want text, why not use `TextBox` instead?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the functionality of a piece of client software so that it's familiar to the users.  The user enters some comma-separated data and clicks 'Check', the system processes the data and highlights the invalid entries so the user can edit them.  RichTextBox seems to be the only way to do this.

Comment: Ah.  Fair enough.  Sorry, I don't know enough about the text area to have a better answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

There are various third-party components that support this kind of functionality (unfortunately paid). For example, [Telerik's RadRichTextBox](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/richtextbox.aspx) supports both highlighting and exporting rich text content as plain text, latter trough component called TxtFormatProvider.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I can't take it up as it's for an open source project.